# Спрощення в групах приголосних. Яке правило ближче до дійсності й правопису?

Tags: правопис, орфографія, чергування

[Follower](/users/585) подав у відповіді на моє [попереднє питання](/q/2728/) наступне посилання:
*[Вікіпідручник. Спрощення у групах приголосних.](//uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%83_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85)*

Бачу декілька проблем:

1. У першому правилі незрозуміло, яке спрощення відбувається у парі „пропуск — пропускний”.
2. У третьому правилі спрощення чомусь відбувається через російську мову.

Я знайшов інший варіант на хорошому ресурсі, якому довіряю:
*[Ed-era. Спрощення в групах приголосних.](//ukr.ed-era.com/12/sproschennya_v_grupah_prigilisnih.html)*

Аж тут взагалі немає правила про спрощення **шчк** до **шк**.

Кому вірити? Де є нормальне правило, в якому немає помилок, але є спрощення потрібної мені пари?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То були надто загальні правила, але давайте вирішимо проблеми.

## Чергування *пропуск — пропускний*

Ніяк, бо виняток

> У групах приголосних **зкн**, **скн** випадає **к** при творенні дієслів із суфіксом **ну**: *бризк – бризнути, брязк – брязнути, тріск – тріснути*, але *випуск – випус**к**ний, виск – вис**к**нути, пропуск – пропус**к**ний* та ін.

## Джерела

Дещо важкувато дати доречну відповідь. Деякі з причин на сьогодення:

- маємо надто запогану чи заслабку культуру свого інтернету
- досі непопулярне створення чи переведеня звичних книг під [відкритий] цифровий формат, особливо для державних установ
- заслабка культура лінґвістики — багато чого совєцького

Ваш ресурс теж доволі спрощений. Хіба що можу порекомендувати оцю [іменку](http://javot.net/mova/orf.htm), тут доволі широко описано, хоча є ймовірність, що теж є помилки чи не все описали.

А на [Webpen](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Pravopys_Pryholosnyh/Sproschnnia_v_prygoloshyh.html) просто [загальні](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Pravopys_Pryholosnyh/spelling_consonants.html) правила. [Деякі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#zmin) норми з чинного [правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#spro).

## Мова

> Спрощення відбувається також у групах приголосних **стц**, **лнц**, **рдц**, **сткл**, **рнц**, **стк**: *місце* (від *мьстьце*), *сонце* (від *солнце*), *серце* (від *сердце*), *скло* (від *стекло*), *чернець – ченця, місто – міський*.

Більшості спрощення ся стосує саме прасловʼянської мови чи похідних від неї. В деяких словах збереглись старі форми чи залишки в відмінках.

- місце

  > **[мі́сце](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=484)** «простір, місцевість; плацента», [*мійсце*] «місце», [*мійце*] «*так само*» Пі, [*місце́*] «невелике місце; невелика площа землі» Бі, [*місцеви́к* «мешканець певної місцевості» Ж, *місце́вість, місци́на* «місце; [містечко Ж]», *місце́вий, місця́ми* «де-не-де»;
  >
  > білоруська [*мѣйсце*] «місце», польська miejsce (＜miestce) «*так само*»;
  >
  > псл. městьce, зменш. від město «місце»; в українській мові ця форма (поряд з *місто* «*так само*) могла бути підтримана впливом польської мови.
  >
  > Див. ще **[мі́сто](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=484)**.
- сонце

  > **[со́нце](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=354)**, [*со́ненько*] (зменш.), *со́нечко* «*те саме*», *сонцеви́к* «астрофізик, який займається дослідженням сонця», [*со́нячник*] «сонячний схил гори» Ч, [*со́нічний*] «сонячний» Нед, *сонце́вий*, [*сонців*], *со́начний*, [*со́няшний*], [*со́яшний*] «сонячний», *відсо́ння* «сонячний бік», [*навсо́нні*] «на сонячному боці», [*осо́вня*] «сонячний бік» Ж, [*осо́внь, осо́нь*] «*те саме*; добре освітлюване сонцем місце», *підсо́ння* «*те саме*», [*при́соннє*] «круг навколо сонця» ЛексПол, *підсо́нячний*, [*посо́лонь*] «за сонцем (ідучи)» Нед;
  >
  > російська *со́лнце*, білоруська *со́нца*, др. *сълньце*, польська słońce, чеська slunce, словацька slnce, вл. słónco, нл. słyńco, болгарська *слъ́нце*, македонська *сонце*, схв. *су̂нце*, слн. sónce, стсл. **слъньце**;
  >
  > псл. *s<sup>ъ</sup>l̥nьce (＜*sŭl(n)‑);
  >
  > споріднене з лит. sáulė, лтс. saũle, прус. saule, гот. sauil, дісл. лат. sōl, гр. ἥλιος (ήἐλιος), двн. suuno, дінд. svar-, ведичне sū́ryaḥ «*те саме*»; іє. *sā́u̯el-／sũl-, *sun-
  >
  > Черных 2 186; Фасмер 3 710—711; Brückner 500; Machek ESJČ 558; Schuster‑Sewc 1305; Младенов 592; Skok 3 361—362; Критенко Вступ 516; Карпенко Назв. зв. неба 73; Mikl. EW 334; Eckert ZfSl 8/6, 882—883, 889; Trautmann 251; Karulis 2 160»161; Pokorny 881.
- *називний множини* [серця](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5) — *родовий* сердець, серць
- *називний однини* [скло](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE) — *множини* стекла