# Як правильно сформувати прикметник від назв Перемишль, Радомишль?

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, запозичені-слова, чергування, приголосні

Чинний Правопис [містить](http://pravopys.kiev.ua/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=2027) якраз цей приклад:

> 4. Деякі слова, узвичаєні без зміни приголосних основи, передаються з ними і на письмі:
>      *баски — баскський, казах — казахський, Перемишль — **перемишльський***

З іншого боку, у Львові [є вулиця Перемиська](http://postcode.in.ua/ua/codes/city/1011/street/1023) (власне, на назву якої я натрапив, зацікавився етимологією і прийшов до цього запитання)

Також, Правопис [містить](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par18p2) наступну тезу:

> Зміни приголосних перед `-СЬК(ИИ)`, `-СТВ(О)`
>   в) `х, ш, с` + `-ськ(ий)`, `-ств(о)` дають `-ськ(ий)`, `-ств(о)`: *залісся — заліський, птах — птаство, товариш — товариський — товариство*.

У цьому джерелі, «товариш», напевне, є найбільш релевантним, бо корінь закінчується на `-ш`. Але не на `-шл(ь)`.

А також є [сучасна книга](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Balyk_Ivan-Borys/Inokentii_Ivan_Vynnytskyi_iepyskop_Peremyskyi_Sambirskyi_i_Sianitskyi_1680-1700/)
Іван-Борис Балик: «Інокентій Іван Винницький, єпископ **Перемиський**, Самбірський і Сяніцький (1680-1700)»

Наскільки я розумію, різні варіанти утворилися внаслідок того, що місто протягом довгого часу було у складі Польщі, де його назва Przemyśl звучала як **Пшемисль**.
І, відповідно утворений прикметник — *пшемиський*.

А багато інших джерел, як-то Wikibooks, [взагалі не наводять](https://uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%83_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85) даного збігу приголосних.

У нас також було подібне запитання, але цей випадок там не розгянуто.

[Спрощення в групах приголосних. Яке правило ближче до дійсності й правопису?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2733/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чинний «Правопис» вимагає писати «перемишльський» (Ви самі це навели в запитання). Але багатьох це не влаштовує, багато хто вважає це вадою чинного «Правопису».

Різні прецеденти і думки:

- Фрагмент з дарчого акту Лева Галицького (не пізніше 1323 року):
  [image: Фрагмент з дарчого акту Лева Галицького]
  (Олег Купчинський, [«Акти та документи галицько-волинського князівства ХІІІ — першої половини XIV століть. Дослідження. Тексти»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Kupchynskyi_Oleh/Akty_ta_dokumenty_Halytsko-Volynskoho_kniazivstva/), с. 138).
- [Іпатіївський літопис](http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat.htm) 1420-х років:
   • «Перемъıшлескоую» ([32](http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat32.htm), [34](http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat34.htm));
   • «перемыслскому», «Перемышльскомоу» ([35](http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat35.htm));
   • «перемышльского», «перемышльскыи», «Перемышлескаго», «Перемышлескии», «Перемышльское», «Перемышльскоую» ([41](http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat41.htm)).
- З [обіжника «Просвіти» 4 жовтня 1937 року](http://www.nasze-slowo.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSC_7248_1024x678.jpg), Перемишль:

  > В районі перемиської філії…

  Ця фотокопія наведена у **[статті «Битва за „переми(шль)ський“» Касі Комар-Мацинської з журналу «Наше Слово» (№ 5, 2018-02-04)](http://www.nasze-slowo.pl/bitva-za-peremishlskij/)** (основне джерело моєї відповіді).
- Загалом вищенаведена стаття Касі Комар-Мацинської створює враження, що за старішими правописами було «перемиський», хоча конкретних цитат з них авторка не наводить, лише спирається на загальну фразу: «Українські географічні назви взагалі треба віддавати на письмі в їх народно-історичній формі» — у харківському «Правописі» 1928 року та твердження філолога Ярина Брилинської-Трояновської: «У правописі 1928 року був „перемиський“. У 1933 році зрадянщений правопис увів норму „перемишльський“. Досі не знаємо, що робити з вул. Перемиською у Львові (дійсно, я перевірила, є вулиця Перемиська у Львові!) і Перемиським князівством. А і ще Перемиською музичною школою. Може, не так усе просто з тими нормами?» — але переглянувши «Правопис» 1928 року, я не побачив підтверджень того, що тодішній правопис начебто вимагав писати так (вищенаведену цитату про українські географічні назви можна трактувати зовсім по-іншому). Але враховуючи численні топоніми зі словом «перемиський», можливо, вони мають рацію, що до другої світової війни була тенденція до «перемиський».
- Фрагмент із тієї ж статті про наш час:

  > Уважний читач «Нашого слова» міг останнім часом помітити мале замішання в записі згаданого прикметника. Головна редакторка тижневика, намагаючись ввести порядок у газеті, пробувала виправити наш закерзонський «перемиський» на згідний з офіційним українським правописом запис «перемишльський». У результаті на короткий час у статтях «Нашого слова», які описували події з-над Сяну, можна було прочитати цю складну, але на 100% правильну конструкцію. Проте наші очі не встигли до неї звикнути, бо на прохання українців Перемишля редакція повернулася до старого запису. <…> Перші арґументи, які чую, коли починаю розпитувати «тутешніх» (місцевих – ред.), чому не погодитись на «перемишльський», це: «Ніхто в Перемишлі так не скаже. Тут завжди говорили „перемиський“, так вже є і все. „Перемишльський“ – це ані не звучить, ані не виглядає. Має бути „перемиський“ завжди і безсмертно!».
- Позиції мовознавців з тієї ж статті:

  - Орися Демська — доктор філологічних наук, професор кафедри української мови Національного університету Києво-Могилянська академія:

    > Перемиський є помилкою в сучасному стандарті літературної української мови. Не бачу потреби змінювати правопис. Сучасна українська мова функціонує на одному полі з російською і суржиком, реґіонально з польською, угорською, румунською, уявіть собі, що кожен захоче якийсь локальний реґіоналізм узаконити… що залишиться від української мови?
  - Мирослава Прихода — видавець, доцент на кафедрі видавничої справи і редаґування Інституту журналістики Київського університету:

    > Тут дуже важливе середовище мови. І середовище, і автор мають право на свої особливі слова. До цього доходить, що людям легше вимовляти,.. тут треба соломонового рішення… Щоб не розбурхувати історію, можна якийсь час вживати і те, і те слово.
  - Ігор Горків — філолог, україніст, член ГУ ОУП, молодий перемишлянин:

    > Це є глибоко закорінене в перемишлянах, і тому не можна цього іґнорувати… Тому, можливо, виходом із ситуації було б додати до правопису версію «перемиський» як допустиму, з історичним та реґіональним обґрунтуванням.
  - Марію Мандрик-Філь — вчителька української мови в загальноосвітньому ліцеї ім. Тараса Шевченка в Білому Борі:

    > Однозначно на це питання відповісти не можна. З одного боку — вчимо літературної мови, і ця мова має свої правила, яких, попри всякі сумніви, мусимо дотримуватись, а особливо, якщо хочемо наближатися до України, мова має бути чистою. Тому ми повинні довіряти фахівцям, які мовою займаються. Проте, з другого боку, мова є живою, її треба відчувати, а краще відчувається те, що рідне і приємне для вуха. Рідне завжди захищаємо, тому зовсім не дивуюся перемишлянам, що вони відстоюють свою традицію. Наша діаспорна тотожність важко сприймає схеми правопису, але і правопис не дуже бере до уваги діалекти діаспори. Тому так бажаною є жива мова, творена на основі знань, досвіду, відчуття і просто любові. Остап Лапський казав: «Мова — радість життя». До речі, наскільки його знаю, він був би за «перемиський», на сто відсотків!